# Upload form - can't upload / post over 120 Kb

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, upload

I am building a website with an upload form. It will upload only up to 120 Kb but the browser times out if anything bigger is tried. No error message, the browser just times out.

#### What I've done so far:

1. Changed all *php.ini* settings, *.htaccess* settings;
2. Tried different browsers;
3. Rebuilt the form on another server (hosting company) and it works fine
   (removed everything from the upload except the bare basics);

This is where it starts getting weird. It works fine on my friends computer.

**I think I've eliminated:**

1. The coding - because it does work;
2. The server - because it works fine on their computers and on my friends computer
3. The browser - Well I've used another web-hosting company and the form works fine with them, so I'm guessing it's not a browser problem, or even my internet connection problem or maybe even settings on my computer?

The problem is on my website the form won't work for anything over 120 kb. On the test website on another server it does work. It's only my computer it doesn't work on other peoples computers it does work. Why and why set at 120 kb. Am I missing something?? I'm taking this very personally, it's as if the internet, my computer, or technology just doesn't like me.

#### EDIT 1:

I've just tried something else. I got another computer and tried it on that to eliminate the possibility it was a problem with the computer. Still doesn't work on a different computer at my house - so I'm thinking my broadband provider? But that doesn't explain why the test website on another server works okay??

Comment: Did you restart Apache after you changed those settings??

Comment: Check your `httpd.conf` additionally! There could be some directives as well!

Comment: hi again, I'm going to go through all these settings once again and double check everything. I'll let you know what happens, thanks.

Comment: hello llia, i haven't got it sorted yet, I've tried everything mentioned here, and to be honest I'd already done most of the recommendations before I came here, but I had a long phone call with my hosting company they said it might be a bug in their system and they'll look into it. If they actually do i'll let you know what happens, but they did say it will take about 48 hours.

Comment: Alright! Keep me posted!

Answer (score 3):

Review your settings in:

*php.ini*

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size=10M

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize=512M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 10

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 30 

; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data. It's a good
; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order to eliminate unexpectedly
; long running scripts.
; http://php.net/max-input-time
max_input_time = 60

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 128M
```

> **It's important after editing *php.ini* file to restart your httpd server, to re-read *php.ini* file!**
>
> Make sure that you set units correctly. There is no shorthand-bytes
>   like **"MB"**. You should use **"K"**, **"M"**, **"G"** for that.
>   Check this PHP [FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes).

*httpd.conf* or/and *.htaccess*

```
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value upload_max_filesize 512M
```

Comment: wow, that was quick, and thanks. but that's not the problem I've eliminated these settings as the problem as I've already changed them and it does work on other peoples computers.

Comment: Hmm.. Let's think what else it could be?

Comment: Did you restart Apache after you changed those settings??

Comment: hello thanks again, I've double checked the php.ini everything is already done on that. restarted apache. and dobule checked the settings in that. still the same problem, like i said it does work, so i'm confident the settings are right.

Comment: Then you must check that the *php.ini* that you're supplying is really that one! Try to debug and make sure that you're really using correct *php.ini* file.

Answer (score 0):

If it really is only your computer, it probably *is* a browser problem.  Have you tried different browsers on your computer?  Have you tried disabling all browser plugins and extensions?

Comment: you people are really quick, yes i've disabled everything on firefox, i've tried google chrome, IE8- doesn't work. I don't think this is the problem because I rebuilt the form on another server and it works fine. so why would it work at all if there was something wrong with the browser and why do all browser not let me upload anything over 120 kb???? thanks but i don't think it's that

Comment: It's not the browser, I bet!

Comment: I agree; this does sound like a server configuration issue.

Comment: Hi Ed, yes I agree but what configuration - what configuration would work on other peoples computers but not mine?

Comment: Configuration files: *php.ini*, httpd.conf, *.htaccess*. If you're using FCGi, check settings there as well (but I doubt).

Comment: See Ilia's comments.  It sounds like the problem is only when you test a local copy or a copy hosted on one particular server.  Whichever it is, edit the php.ini, httpd.conf, and .htaccess files for that machine.

Comment: @user2966159 Look what I had once. I had perfectly working contact form. After PHP update it just stopped working. I just was trying to post a form and it was returned cut amount of data, that represented wrong value in `post_max_size`. It was like few Kb. I bet you will not be able to post anything bigger than that. Check that you're really loading correct `php.ini`, just rename it, restart `httpd` and see what you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you changed all of your PHP settings in php.ini & you are sure that they are set—perhaps via `phpinfo()` reflecting your settings—and it still doesn’t work it sounds like it might be a firewall issue where the network itself is limiting content being uploaded.

Unclear what this server is or where you have it setup, but I bet a firewall setting is in play.

Comment: yeah, i thought that, i've tried it with my firewall off, but why would the firewall allow it to work on the test website but not on the one i'm actually trying to build, that's just prejudice!

Comment: It's all sent via port 80/443? What firewall could do here, really?